# does Request.Querystring automatically url decode a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, url, url-rewriting

I'm working with a page where I have a url like:
/directory/company/manufacturer

Using some re-write rules this gets re-written

testing with /directory/company/dunkin%26donuts/

Some manufacturers have an ampersand in their name. So I thought I could just replace the ampersand with `%26`. However, when I debug the code and hover over `Request.QueryString` it shows me `{qq=company&manf=dunkin&donuts&cond=}` and `Request.QueryString["manf"]` gives me 'dunkin'

If I use `%24` ($) instead of ampersand, hovering over `Request.QueryString` gives me
`{qs=company&manf=dunkin%24donuts&cond=}` and `Request.QueryString["manf"]` gives me 'dunkin$donuts'

I don't understand the different behavior here. Why does it seem as though the url-encoded value for an ampersand gets decoded before you actually request a specific key, but another url-encoded character, like a dollar sign, only gets decoded after you actually request that specific key?

Is this a recent change? I always thought `Request.QueryString[key]` returned the actual text without decoding it first. Or does it have something to do with url re-writes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replacing the ampersand with `%26` should cause that value to be escaped, so `Request.QueryString["manf"]` would yield `dunkin&donuts`.

The asker of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561954/asp-net-urlencode-ampersand-for-use-in-query-string) ended up realizing that some other code on the same page ended up pre-decoding his ampersands. Is it possible that you've got something similar happening? Perhaps some javascript is decoding the `%26` into an ampersand before sending it to your server. Try using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to see the actual URL string that is being sent from the browser.

### Update

After looking at the question again, I realize that you're probably using a URL Rewriter. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529857/ampersands-in-urlrewriter-query-strings) describes a similar problem, and I don't know of a solution for sure, but you may want to try double-encoding the ampersand using `%2526` instead of `%26`.

Comment: It's possible something else is playing with the url - either the rewrite or maybe some other pre-existing code on the site. This isn't a site I created but one i took over from someone else. So there might be some other code involved here. Hadn't thought of that. I'll do some digging. thanks. I'll update this question once i have more info

Comment: dbl encoding didnt work btw - dunkin%2526donuts got turned into dunkin&25donuts

Comment: Not sure what changed, but your suggestion for dbl encoding seems to be working now. I actually tried doing it like %25%32%36, which also worked. but then the browser i think auto-converted that to %2526 and it started working

Comment: @merk: You probably did %2625 the first time.

Answer (score 43):

ASP.NET automatically calls `UrlDecode()` when you access a property by key index (i.e. (`Request.QueryString["key"]`).

If you want it encoded, just do:

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["key"]);`

In terms of the ampersand specifically, that is a special case character because it is already used as a query string delimeter. URL Encoding and decoding an ampersand should always give you `&` for that very reason.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I think I only answered half of his question looking back, I've edited to include why exactly ampersands are different.

Comment: I realize it's a special character - i just dont understand why it seems to be getting decoded at a different point then compared to the dollar sign. When i hover over Request.QueryString in VS2010 while debugging the page, i see the urlencoded value for the dollar sign - %24. But when it comes to the ampersand, i always see the decoded value.

Comment: Is there a reference to a MSDN article stating that the UrlDecode is automatically called?

Comment: @MADCookie I don't know buddy, but if you try debugging it yourself you'll see for sure (that's what I did) :)

Comment: Debugging is what i've been doing and, yes, I see the value from Request("blah") where blah=Some%2fValue is giving me Some/Value. I just want to hear it from the horse's mouth before I direct my team mates to make a change. 

This is ignoring the question: what other magic is taking place? What encoding magic is on the Response object?

Comment: Problem with this is if you do want special characters in the querystring. For example I am using ';' to separate a list of values, sometimes those values contain ampersands. When referring to that querystring with Request.Querystring[key] it replaces %26 with an ampersand. UrlEncoding that keeps my ampersand as a %26 but converts my ';' to %3b, thus loosing my separators.

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I think a solution might be to modify the UrlRewrite rule to something like.

```
    <rule name="TagPage" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(tag)/([^/]+)/?$"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="ListByTags.aspx?tag={UrlEncode:{R:2}}"/>
    </rule>
```

The important line here is the {UrlEncode:{R:2}}. It solved the problem for me!